# How to decouple html/js code from laravel4 templates?

Tags: templates, laravel-4

I want to separate html code from my laravel template (*.blade.php) file . I have following code in my dashboard.blade.php template :

```
<h1>Dashboard</h1>
<p>Welcome to your Dashboard. You rock!</p>
<div class="bubbletree-wrapper">
    <div class="bubbletree"></div>
</div>
```

I want to separate this html code from here and want to move it to another file , with extension either *.html or *.tpl or any other except *.php .

Is it possible to do so ? Please help me on this .

Thanks.

Comment: Why? `.blade.php` is here exactly for this. It is template file. It should hold HTML code. Your question is like "I want to travel by car to work, but I don't want to travel by car"

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anyone 100% decoupling HTML/CSS, but you can follow some Design Patterns, like Presenter, and use Laravel Blade so it be very little coupled.

Name a view `home.blade.php` and add your code to it and change your code to:

```
<h1>{{$pageTitle}}</h1>
<p>{{$welcomeMessage}}</p>
<div class="bubbletree-wrapper">
    <div class="bubbletree"></div>
</div>
```

Create a route using:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function() {

    return View::make('home', 
                        array(
                            '$pageTitle' => 'Dashboard', 
                            'welcomeMessage' => 'Welcome to your Dashboard. You rock!'
                        )
                    );

});
```

See? It's almost 100% decoupled, but you cannot decouple 100% or you'll not be able to show your dynamic data in your final HTML.

Also, Blade helps you organize your code, so you can have a layout, let's call it `layout.blade.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Your Application </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>

    <body class="">

        @yield('contentSection')

    </body>

</html>
```

You have one single line of Blade in it, just to add your page contents, now you can create your home view as:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('contentSection')
    <h1>{{$pageTitle}}</h1>
    <p>{{$welcomeMessage}}</p>
    <div class="bubbletree-wrapper">
        <div class="bubbletree"></div>
    </div>
@stop
```

And blade will render this HTML for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Your Application </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>

    <body class="">

        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <p>Welcome to your Dashboard. You rock!</p>
        <div class="bubbletree-wrapper">
            <div class="bubbletree"></div>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```